# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/junit/platform/commons/util/ClassNamePatternFilterUtils when trying run mockito junit5 test with gradle

Tags: java, spring, gradle, mockito, junit5

I received the following error

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/junit/platform/commons/util/ClassNamePatternFilterUtils
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.LauncherFactory.loadAndFilterTestExecutionListeners(LauncherFactory.java:122)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.LauncherFactory.create(LauncherFactory.java:108)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.LauncherFactory.create(LauncherFactory.java:75)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestLoader.(JUnit5TestLoader.java:34)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:64)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.ReflectAccess.newInstance(ReflectAccess.java:128)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.ReflectionFactory.newInstance(ReflectionFactory.java:350)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:645)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.createRawTestLoader(RemoteTestRunner.java:371)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.createLoader(RemoteTestRunner.java:366)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.defaultInit(RemoteTestRunner.java:310)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.init(RemoteTestRunner.java:225)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:209)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.junit.platform.commons.util.ClassNamePatternFilterUtils
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:606)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:168)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
... 16 more

and this my gradle file

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb' 
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb-reactive' 
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux' 
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools' 
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-json'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    annotationProcessor 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok' 
    runtime 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }
    testCompile('org.apache.commons:commons-compress:1.19')
    testImplementation 'io.projectreactor:reactor-test'
    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-collections4', version: '4.4'
    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.8.1'
    compile group: 'commons-codec', name: 'commons-codec', version: '1.14'
    compile group: 'org.json', name: 'json', version: '20180813'  
    compile group: 'com.opencsv', name: 'opencsv', version: '5.1' 
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava
    compile group: 'com.google.guava', name: 'guava', version: '28.1-jre'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk
     compile group: 'com.amazonaws', name: 'aws-java-sdk', version: '1.11.852'

    compile("io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:2.9.2"){
     exclude group:"com.google.guava", module:"guava"
    }
    compile("io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:2.9.2"){
     exclude group:"com.google.guava", module:"guava"
    }

    runtime  group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-dependencies', version: 'Hoxton.SR6', ext: 'pom'
    compile group: 'io.spring.gradle', name: 'dependency-management-plugin', version: '1.0.9.RELEASE'
    implementation ('org.reflections:reflections:0.9.10') {
        exclude group: 'com.google.code.findbugs', module: 'annotations'
    }
    implementation 'commons-io:commons-io:2.5'
    implementation("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-openfeign:2.2.0.RELEASE"){
     exclude group:"ch.qos.logback", module:"logback-classic"
    }
    implementation 'io.github.openfeign:feign-jackson:11.0'
    implementation 'io.github.openfeign:feign-httpclient:11.0'
    compile group: 'io.github.openfeign.form', name: 'feign-form-spring', version: '3.5.0'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-xml:2.11.0'
    implementation 'org.alfresco:alfresco-data-model:6.19@jar'
    implementation 'xerces:xercesImpl:2.9.1@jar'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Comment: Could you provide some information about the class you wanted to test and the test/config you got?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found missing the following lines in build.gradle file

```
testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.platform:junit-platform-commons:1.7.1'
```

after adding this it works completely fine.

Comment: This shouldn’t be necessary. My guess is that you have incompatible versions of JUnit referenced somehow. If you want to know please show your full build.gradle file.

Comment: Added my gradle file in the question. Please refer

Comment: I'm quite sure somewhere in your dependencies a version incompatibility is hiding since `ClassNamePatternFilterUtils` came into being with junit-platform 5.7. Maybe you are using a spring boot version < 2.4? If so switch to a newer version of Spring boot and your problem should go away.

Comment: This answer worked for me too.  (johanneslink, I am using spring boot version < 2.4, but I can't change that right now.)  I was only seeing the error when trying to run tests in Eclipse; running the tests through gradle was succeeding.